# How can I send the value from Node to HTML for processing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Can I get Node values ​​as JavaScript arguments in HTML (Node code value -> JavaScript inside `index.html`)?

I couldn't find a way.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const idxRouter = require('./router/index.js');

app.use('/',idxRouter);
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express'); //node express framework
const router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
const db = require('../dbconfig/db');
const num = 2;
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    function test(num) {
        try {
            db.query('SELECT a.explain from explain a  where no =' + num, function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(rows);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
    test(num);
    res.end(fs.readFileSync( '/Users/hoon/node/drawio/src/main/webapp/index.html'));
});//app.get '/' end

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide some code examples. I imagine you use expressjs? If so, which template engine do you use?

Comment: I was in a hurry. The document has been modified. thank you for the reply

Comment: Did you try my solution? I can edit it soon, so it fits your needs.

Comment: thank you but I have not applied the solution yet. I will try and post a review.

Comment: I adjusted my solution to fit your use case. Please try it out and mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

**/router/index.js**

```
const express = require('express'); //node express framework
const router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
const db = require('../dbconfig/db');
const num = 2;

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    function test(num) {
        try {
            db.query('SELECT a.explain from explain a  where no =' + num, function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                return rows;
                console.log(rows);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    };
    res.render('index.html', {
        rows: test(num)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const idxRouter = require('./router/index.js');

app.use('/',idxRouter);

nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**/views/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ol>
        {% for row in rows %}
          <!--replace .name with your column/key you want to show -->
        <li>{{ row.name }}</li> 
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
</body>

</html>
```